# What's the cleanest and easiest way to sort an array of numbers in a predfined order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array of IDs (integers) like so `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

But they need to be in the following order, `[2,1,5,3,6,7,4]`. What's the best way to do this? I have underscore js, and jquery at my disposal.

Is it a case of just looping through each ID and comparing it off of the next one?

The array of ID's could be in any order when i get them, and also there could be say.. 3 of them or any number of them. i.e. `[2,1,4]` or `[4,5,2,6]`.

Comment: What is the rule ?

Comment: I've managed to find a clean, more readable solution in my pinion, although it may not be as efficient as the answers mentioned elsewhere.

`const orgTypes = [4, 6, 3, 1, 2];`  
`const sortedIds = [];`  
        `const sortOrder = [2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4];  

        _.each(sortOrder, (num) => {
            _.each(orgTypes, (id) => {
                if (num === id) {
                    sortedIds.push(id);
                }

            });
        });`

Comment: if this is javascript code u r talking about then Array.sort() method is the cleanest way to write your code.